# ps pipe and grep shell scripting illegal argument

Tags: shell

New to shell scripting and just writing a little script to check if a process is running, if I use

```
PROCESS_NUM="ps -ef | grep '$1' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l"
```

I get a "ps: illegal argument: |" error although if I echo out PROCESS_NUM and ctrl paste in the line it works just fine manually. Not sure why the | pipe is being troublesome here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to assig the output of `ps -ef | grep '$1' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l` command to `PROCESS_NUM` variable, you need to use below:

```
PROCESS_NUM=`ps -ef | grep '$1' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l`
```

or

```
PROCESS_NUM=$(ps -ef | grep '$1' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l)
```

Using "", will treat the value inside of it as a string, except for some special character

Comment: much appreciated!